# No @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'isequaltostring:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsstring

I have an if statement inside my sign up button with multiple variables like checking to make sure the user filled out all of the values and if the email is equal to the confirmed email. Everything works below besides I keep getting the error: No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'isequaltostring:' Any help is much appreciated!

```
NSString *name      = fieldSignUpName.text;
NSString *password  = fieldSignUpPassword.text;
NSString *phone     = fieldTelephone.text;
NSString *email     = fieldSignUpEmail.text;
NSString *emailtwo  = emailcopy.text;

if ((name.length != 0) && (password.length != 0) && (email.length != 0) && (phone.length != 0) && ([email isequaltoString: emailtwo]))

 //continues statement...
```

Comment: Objective-C is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods are case-sensitive. You have

> `isequaltostring:`

which NSString doesn't have a selector for. The correct method is:

> `isEqualToString:`

Notice the capital E, T, and S.

For more information on Objective-C conventions, see Apple's documentation [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your code: `isEqualToString:` is the correct method name, which is is different from `isequaltoString:` which you have in your code. (notice the capitalised "e" in "equal")

Comment: Why the down vote on this answer? It's correct. Milo's answer might be explained a little better, but this answer is correct. (voted)

Comment: Aw, thanks guys :) I agree, Milo's is better explained. I'll try to add more detail in the future!

Comment: @ev0lution thank you for your answer! Both were correct and helped me solve my problem but I went with the first answer submitted. Thank you though!